# Use [Authenticate] attribute in MVC controller using sessions to authorize users?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I have been searching for similar solutions online but everything seems overcomplicating, currently, I have a UserController that I only want users that are logged in to access, my current solution involves using if statements however I was wondering if it's possible to use the [Authorize] attribute and apply it to methods or the entire controller perhaps?

```
public class UserController : ASessionController {
    public UserController (IAmazonDynamoDB dynamoDbClient, DynamoDBContext dynamoDbContext) : base(dynamoDbClient, dynamoDbContext) {
    }

    // [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index () {
        // check session variable
        if(!UserIsLoggedIn()){ /*redirect to sign in*/ } 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am not understanding if this is the purpose of the Authorize attribute? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried using this attribute for the entire controller?

Comment: I think its possible but the reason is that every action under this controller would have the [Autherize] attribute, either way i prefer having [Autherize] rather than an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Authorize attribute on endpoints and / or the Controller itself
It will force the User to be authenticated to again access to the decorated item.
In addition you can also restrict it to authenticated users with a given or multiple roles like in the example

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Guest")]
public IActionResult NotAnIIndex()
{
    ...
}
```

But you should read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0) tuturial